# How do I move folders in MS Teams

Tags: file, move, microsoft-teams

I am using MS Teams.
I am in a team, in the Files tab. I can insert edit delete files. I can move files using the "Move" command from the context menu.

I need to move a folder that I just created, under another folder.
How can I do that? There's no "Move" command in the context menu.
Thankx

Comment: This really should be on [webapps.se] instead of here because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not currently possible, by design.

When you move or rename a folder from outside Teams (e.g. using SharePoint) links to the files in that folder break (we link by path instead of by ID). This is something we will fix in the future, but for now we don't support moving folders for this reason.

Comment: Actually, I believe it is possible through a roundabout process: From the parent folder, select Open in Sharepoint.  If your default browser is not IE, copy the link into IE.  In the lower left, select Return to Classic Sharepoint.  Click on the Library tab, select Open in Explorer.  do the same in the destination folder so you have two Explorer windows.  you cannot Move, but you can copy/Paste and then remove the old.  This also works for moving folders across channels.

Comment: A similar method, is to [Sync the parent folders](https://www.google.com/search?q=add+teams+folder+to+file+explorer&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS751US751&oq=add+teams+folder+to&aqs=chrome.0.0l2j69i57j0l5.3955j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_myq8XpffKIvt-gT-14nYAw32) to your File Explorer, then copy the the sub-folders from one to the other, as explained by @Jim

Comment: @Jim The Sharepoint browser application seems to allow you to move folders now. So just "Open in Sharepoint" from MS Teams and then move the folder [the same way you would move a file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/move-or-copy-files-in-teams-f83ed547-359b-4fc8-bf5a-60467f53dd60). So for some reason the MS Teams application is missing features that are in the browser... I'm using Firefox 92 on Debian 11 by the way.